# Why I receive "CSRF token mismatch" while running tests in laravel?

Tags: laravel, phpunit, csrf

I want to run my tests without receiving "CSRF token mismatch" exceptions. In the laravel documentation is noted that:

> The CSRF middleware is automatically disabled when running tests.

the line of code where the exception is thrown looks like this:

```
$response = $this->json('POST', route('order.create'), [
     'product_id', $product->id
]);
```

and for running tests I am working in my zsh terminal:

```
php artisan test --env=testing
```

This is my test class:

```
<?php

   namespace Tests\Feature;

   use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
   use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
   use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
   use Tests\TestCase;

  class SessionCartTest extends TestCase
  {
      public function testExample()
      {
          $product = \App\Product::inRandomOrder()->first();
          $response = $this->postJson(route('order.insert'), [
              'product_id' => $product->id,
          ]);
          $response->assertStatus(200); // here I receive 419
      }
  }
```

What am I doing wrong and how could I fix this? I am using laravel 7.

Comment: Why are you using an artisan command to run the tests?
What happens when you run phpunit on your console?
Are you sure that you are getting a CSRF exception?

Comment: Its the same when running phpunit. I am dumping the response and I see what's inside, also the HTTP error code is 419.

Comment: Can you include your test class?

Comment: @DigitalDrifter I added my test class in the question

Comment: in the Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken constructor somehow sets the $app->env to "local" instead of "testing"

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I ran into this problem x times now and each time I fix it by running:
`php artisan config:clear`

Comment: I need to make a mug that says this or something. So many times i've found some very strange behavior and this has fixed it.

Comment: Found so many strange behavior. This saved my OT. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks so much. I saw red all across the board and panicked...

Answer (score 18):

Probably the `APP_ENV` is not being set to `testing`.

You can set a ENV variable in the command line by preceding the php command.

So on your case set the environment to testing and run the artisan command by:

```
APP_ENV=testing php artisan test
```

Comment: Same. Indeed, the problem is the environment not being set correctly, even though I added it explicitly. Something is overwriting it... before calling the Middleware

Answer (score 1):

Your data array is wrong. Try the following change:

```
$response = $this->postJson(route('order.insert'), [
      'product_id' => $product->id, // use the arrow notation here.
 ]);
```

Comment: yes, that's a typo, fixed, but I still get the exception "Expected status code 200 but received 419. Failed asserting that false is true." Maybe is something super obvious that I miss..

Comment: that's how my route is defined in web Route::post('/order', 'OrderController@insert')->name('order.insert');

Comment: Try running `php artisan cache:clear` before running your tests.

Comment: I fixed it, it was from the config cache. I also had to remove the lines from phpunit.xml regarding DB_CONNECTION sqlite and DB_DATABASE. Thanks for all the hints!

Comment: To be clear, its was the `php artisan config:clear` command which did the trick for me

Answer (score 1):

When you are running tests on Docker where the APP_ENV is hard coded with other values than testing (dev, local) in docker-compose.yaml file, phpunit cannot execute tests properly.
You will need to delete the all APP_ENV in docker files.

Answer (score 1):

This works by setting a custom csrf-token

```
$this
   ->withSession(['_token' => 'bzz'])
   ->postJson('/url', ['_token' => 'bzz', 'other' => 'data']);
```